# Oracle: get all table names which i had created tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get all table names from query.

My current query is

```
select table_name from all_tables
```

but it's retrieved all tables from database. I need only my created tables.

Comment: Use USER_TABLES instead of ALL_TABLES.

Comment: it's working, thank you so much